# Change focus to ComboBox

Tags: winforms

I need to change focus to a ComboBox in my Windows Form on an event (say SelectedIndexChange event of another ComboBox). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `.Focus()` of the control you want to give focus to.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can .Select() like this:

```
comboBox1.Select();
```